# How to get the standard behavior of lead convert in a custom page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lead-conversion

We Duplicate rules enabled.

When converting a lead, a return page, with possible duplicates appear, with buttons: 'Convert to Selected' or 'Convert to New'

We have a custom page for the lead convert, but I would like to get this behavior on my page.

[image]

How is that possible?
Which class/method do I need to call?

Database.LeadConvertResult - return the result set of duplicates.

I want that data will overwrite existing lead data.

I use this to display the list of available contacts, adding a radio button, how do I use it in the 'Save and ignore' dupcliate?

VF Page

```
<!-- added for duplicates -->
<apex:pageBlock title="Duplicate Records" rendered="{!hasDuplicateResult}">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!duplicateRecords}" var="item">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!item['Id']}">{!item['Name']}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!item['OwnerId']}"/>
        </apex:column>                
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Account</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!item['AccountId']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Last Modified Date</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!item['LastModifiedDate']}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Convert (Ignore Alert)" action="{!convertLeadIgnoreDuplicate}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>   
</apex:pageBlock> 
<!-- End code -->
```

Comment: Just curious, `Database.LeadConvertResult` doesn't return these details?

Comment: It does, how to configure the buttons?

Comment: Are you asking specificlly how to add a `Convert & Ignore` button? Do you have the rest of the page working? Just that button can be done via the `DMLOptions`, specifically [DMLOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm#apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader). This should ignore any duplicate rules you have & just save the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result was using the 'hadduplicaterecords' that is returning from the Database.leadConvert.

I have 2 buttons, that alternate accordingly.

```
        <div id="buttonBlock">
            <apex:commandButton value="Convert (Ignore Alert)" action="{!convertLeadIgnoreDuplicate}" rendered="{!hasDuplicateResult}"/>           
            <apex:commandButton value="Convert" id="convertButton"  action="{!convertLead}"  rendered="{!hasDuplicateResult == false}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" />
        </div>
```

The supporting method in the contorller is

```
public PageReference convertLeadIgnoreDuplicate() {
    PageReference pageRef = null;
    ignoreDuplicateAndConvert = true;

    pageRef = convertLead();
    return pageRef;
}
```